# How to reuse puppet SSL certificates

Tags: amazon-ec2, puppet, user-data

I would like have a setup where  my  ec2 instances are getting  terminated  sometimes and  new nodes comes up with the same  host name .My puppetserver supposed  to have the old certificates  with them  and instantly push the configs via the required modules.

Is this a viable solution?In this case do I need to keep the ssl certs of clients  and push them to the ec2instnces via  user-data ? what   would  be  the best alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really think of too many arguments against certificate re-use, only that `puppet cert clean "$certname"` on the CA master is so simple that I can't really think of a reason to re-use certificate names.

That said, I'd recommend building some kind of pipeline that includes certificate cleaning upon destruction of your ec2 instances. This is fairly easy to do in a  [terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) workflow with the [AWS Terraform Provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html) and [local-exec provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html). For each `aws_instance` you create, you'd also create a `local-exec` resource, and specify the `local-exec`only executes at destruction time: `when = "destroy"`.

If you're re-using hostnames for convenience, maybe it would be wise to instead rely on dns to point to the new hosts instead of relying on the hostnames themselves and stop worrying about `puppet cert clean`.